# How might work flag, that do not specified in Developer Android Docs?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wakelock, powermanager

I reverse engineer one application that turn on / off screen on shake. It uses WakeLock by PowerManager

```
this.mWakelock = this.mPowermanager.newWakeLock(268435466, "ShakeUnlock"); //LockService.java activity
```

Flag that is written here, 268435466. I tried to understand what does it stand for. But this value does not specified in [Google Dev Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#newWakeLock(int,%20java.lang.String)).
None of the constants have this value.

But it works properly.
How so?

Full code of Android Studio project: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BMKl26X2IJOxXXyCdfwNcHA5TKE9-jjm)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is `PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` value of it is `0x1000000a = 268435466`